# IOS: country code

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, country-codes

I have this code to obtain a code country, but I want to see all code country available; then I can do some "if" to implement in my app

```
NSLocale *locale = [NSLocale currentLocale];
NSString *countryCode = [locale objectForKey: NSLocaleCountryCode]; 
NSLog(@"countryCode:%@", countryCode);
```

can you help me?

Comment: Avoid using country names in certain language (say english). Make a dynamic list of country names as per answers below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Run this code to see all available localizers:

```
NSLog(@"availableLocaleIdentifiers: %@", [NSLocale availableLocaleIdentifiers]);
```

You can do the same thing for `commonISOCurrencyCodes`, `ISOCountryCodes`, `ISOCurrencyCodes`, `ISOCurrencyCodes`, `preferredLanguages`.

Answer (score 16):

This is an array with all country codes:

```
[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Afghanistan(+93)", @"Albania(+355)",@"Algeria(+213)",@"American Samoa(+1684)",@"Andorra(+376)",@"Angola(+244)",@"Anguilla(+1264)",@"Antarctica(+672)",@"Antigua and Barbuda(+1268)",@"Argentina(+54)",@"Armenia(+374)",@"Aruba(+297)",@"Australia(+61)",@"Austria(+43)",@"Azerbaijan(+994)",@"Bahamas(+1242)",@"Bahrain(+973)",@"Bangladesh(+880)",@"Barbados(+1246)"@"Belarus(+375)",@"Belgium(+32)",@"Belize(+501)",@"Benin(+229)",@"Bermuda(+1441)",@"Bhutan(+975)",@"Bolivia(+591)",@"Bosnia and Herzegovina(+387)",@"Botswana(+267)"@"Brazil(+55)",@"British Virgin Islands(+1284)",@"Brunei(+673)",@"Bulgaria(+359)",@"Burkina Faso(+226)",@"Burma (Myanmar)(+95)",@"Burundi(+257)",@"Cambodia(+855)",@"Cameroon(+237)",@"Canada(+1)",@"Cape Verde(+238)",@"Cayman Islands(+1345)",@"Central African Republic(+236)",@"Chad(+235)",@"Chile(+56)",@"China(+86)",@"Christmas Island(+61)",@"Cocos (Keeling) Islands(+61)",@"Colombia(+57)",@"Comoros(+269)",@"Cook Islands(+682)",@"Costa Rica(+506)",@"Croatia(+385)",@"Cuba(+53)",@"Cyprus(+357)",@"Czech Republic(+420)",@"Democratic Republic of the Congo(+243)",@"Denmark(+45)",@"Djibouti(+253)",@"Dominica(+1767)",@"Dominican Republic(+1809)",@"Ecuador(+593)",@"Egypt(+20)",@"El Salvador(+503)",@"Equatorial Guinea(+240)",@"Eritrea(+291)",@"Estonia(+372)",@"Ethiopia(+251)",@"Falkland Islands(+500)",@"Faroe Islands(+298)",@"Fiji(+679)",@"Finland(+358)",@"France (+33)",@"French Polynesia(+689)",@"Gabon(+241)",@"Gambia(+220)",@"Gaza Strip(+970)",@"Georgia(+995)",@"Germany(+49)",@"Ghana(+233)",@"Gibraltar(+350)",@"Greece(+30)",@"Greenland(+299)",@"Grenada(+1473)",@"Guam(+1671)",@"Guatemala(+502)",@"Guinea(+224)",@"Guinea-Bissau(+245)",@"Guyana(+592)",@"Haiti(+509)",@"Holy See (Vatican City)(+39)",@"Honduras(+504)",@"Hong Kong(+852)",@"Hungary(+36)",@"Iceland(+354)",@"India(+91)",@"Indonesia(+62)",@"Iran(+98)",@"Iraq(+964)",@"Ireland(+353)",@"Isle of Man(+44)",@"Israel(+972)",@"Italy(+39)",@"Ivory Coast(+225)",@"Jamaica(+1876)",@"Japan(+81)",@"Jordan(+962)",@"Kazakhstan(+7)",@"Kenya(+254)",@"Kiribati(+686)",@"Kosovo(+381)",@"Kuwait(+965)",@"Kyrgyzstan(+996)",@"Laos(+856)",@"Latvia(+371)",@"Lebanon(+961)",@"Lesotho(+266)",@"Liberia(+231)",@"Libya(+218)",@"Liechtenstein(+423)",@"Lithuania(+370)",@"Luxembourg(+352)",@"Macau(+853)",@"Macedonia(+389)",@"Madagascar(+261)",@"Malawi(+265)",@"Malaysia(+60)",@"Maldives(+960)",@"Mali(+223)",@"Malta(+356)",@"MarshallIslands(+692)",@"Mauritania(+222)",@"Mauritius(+230)",@"Mayotte(+262)",@"Mexico(+52)",@"Micronesia(+691)",@"Moldova(+373)",@"Monaco(+377)",@"Mongolia(+976)",@"Montenegro(+382)",@"Montserrat(+1664)",@"Morocco(+212)",@"Mozambique(+258)",@"Namibia(+264)",@"Nauru(+674)",@"Nepal(+977)",@"Netherlands(+31)",@"Netherlands Antilles(+599)",@"New Caledonia(+687)",@"New Zealand(+64)",@"Nicaragua(+505)",@"Niger(+227)",@"Nigeria(+234)",@"Niue(+683)",@"Norfolk Island(+672)",@"North Korea (+850)",@"Northern Mariana Islands(+1670)",@"Norway(+47)",@"Oman(+968)",@"Pakistan(+92)",@"Palau(+680)",@"Panama(+507)",@"Papua New Guinea(+675)",@"Paraguay(+595)",@"Peru(+51)",@"Philippines(+63)",@"Pitcairn Islands(+870)",@"Poland(+48)",@"Portugal(+351)",@"Puerto Rico(+1)",@"Qatar(+974)",@"Republic of the Congo(+242)",@"Romania(+40)",@"Russia(+7)",@"Rwanda(+250)",@"Saint Barthelemy(+590)",@"Saint Helena(+290)",@"Saint Kitts and Nevis(+1869)",@"Saint Lucia(+1758)",@"Saint Martin(+1599)",@"Saint Pierre and Miquelon(+508)",@"Saint Vincent and the Grenadines(+1784)",@"Samoa(+685)",@"San Marino(+378)",@"Sao Tome and Principe(+239)",@"Saudi Arabia(+966)",@"Senegal(+221)",@"Serbia(+381)",@"Seychelles(+248)",@"Sierra Leone(+232)",@"Singapore(+65)",@"Slovakia(+421)",@"Slovenia(+386)",@"Solomon Islands(+677)",@"Somalia(+252)",@"South Africa(+27)",@"South Korea(+82)",@"Spain(+34)",@"Sri Lanka(+94)",@"Sudan(+249)",@"Suriname(+597)",@"Swaziland(+268)",@"Sweden(+46)",@"Switzerland(+41)",@"Syria(+963)",@"Taiwan(+886)",@"Tajikistan(+992)",@"Tanzania(+255)",@"Thailand(+66)",@"Timor-Leste(+670)",@"Togo(+228)",@"Tokelau(+690)",@"Tonga(+676)",@"Trinidad and Tobago(+1868)",@"Tunisia(+216)",@"Turkey(+90)",@"Turkmenistan(+993)",@"Turks and Caicos Islands(+1649)",@"Tuvalu(+688)",@"Uganda(+256)",@"Ukraine(+380)",@"United Arab Emirates(+971)",@"United Kingdom(+44)",@"United States(+1)",@"Uruguay(+598)",@"US Virgin Islands(+1340)",@"Uzbekistan(+998)",@"Vanuatu(+678)",@"Venezuela(+58)",@"Vietnam(+84)",@"Wallis and Futuna(+681)",@"West Bank(970)",@"Yemen(+967)",@"Zambia(+260)",@"Zimbabwe(+263)",nil];
```

Comment: Not a good idea to use if you want to read countrynames in other language (say Russian) and have to compare countrynames.

Answer (score 0):

Better to rely on the NSLocale for countryCode & other language/locale dependent strings. For example: `Egypt` in Russian is `Египет`. Avoid using hardcoded country lists like https://stackoverflow.com/a/22660792/342794.

Use `[NSLocale ISOCountryCodes]`.

```
// Example:
for (NSString *code in [NSLocale ISOCountryCodes])
{
    // Convert the code to a name: 
    NSString *countryName = [[NSLocale currentLocale] displayNameForKey:NSLocaleCountryCode value:code];
}
```

From `NSLocale.h`; look at other similar properties

```
@property (class, readonly, copy) NSArray<NSString *> *availableLocaleIdentifiers;
@property (class, readonly, copy) NSArray<NSString *> *ISOLanguageCodes;
@property (class, readonly, copy) NSArray<NSString *> *ISOCountryCodes;
@property (class, readonly, copy) NSArray<NSString *> *ISOCurrencyCodes;
@property (class, readonly, copy) NSArray<NSString *> *commonISOCurrencyCodes;
```