# how to provide drop down list of countries for the user from Parse backend in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, parse-platform

I'm new to Swift, this is my first app.I want to implement a drop-down list of clubs for the user to select while registering/signing up on the app for the first time from my club table in Parse. How can this be added? does this implementation need CoreData ?

Answer (score 2):

To provide the dropdown list, the best option to use in iOS is `UIPickerView`, use `UIPickerView` to show the list of your clubs and user can select the option from it.

Now regarding fetching the data from parse, so when user appears on registration page then in the `viewDidLoad` method you have to fetch the data from Parse , and as the data is successfully received assign that data to your `UIPickerView` datasource.

Regarding `CoreData`, the use of `CoreData` completely depends on how frequently the clubs are added and deleted from the database, if they are frequently changed then every time during SignUp you have to fetch the data from parse, so that user will be able to see the new clubs.If the clubs are not changed frequently then store the data of clubs into `CoreData` and the next time when another user register from the same device, populate the `UIPickerView` data from `CoreData`.

Lastly I would like to say that the use of CoreData is completely depends on how your app is gonna work.

Comment: Firstly thanks @Rajatp for the suggestion.. Never worked on UIPicker ; learning Swift by examples (code and learn)

Comment: Ok so every time you have to fetch the data from the Parse and populate your UIPickerView no need to use CoreData in your app.

Answer (score 0):

Part of the question regarding UIPicker* & CoreData has been answered by @Rajat.

Rely on the NSLocale for countryCode & other language/locale dependent strings.

Use `[NSLocale ISOCountryCodes]`.

```
// Example:
for (NSString *code in [NSLocale ISOCountryCodes])
{
    // Convert the code to a name: 
    NSString *countryName = [[NSLocale currentLocale] displayNameForKey:NSLocaleCountryCode value:code];
}
```

From `NSLocale.h`; look at other similar properties

```
@property (class, readonly, copy) NSArray<NSString *> *availableLocaleIdentifiers;
@property (class, readonly, copy) NSArray<NSString *> *ISOLanguageCodes;
@property (class, readonly, copy) NSArray<NSString *> *ISOCountryCodes;
@property (class, readonly, copy) NSArray<NSString *> *ISOCurrencyCodes;
@property (class, readonly, copy) NSArray<NSString *> *commonISOCurrencyCodes;
```

Avoid using hardcoded country lists like https://stackoverflow.com/a/22660792/342794.

For example: `Egypt` in Russian is `Египет`.

From my answer here: [IOS: country code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9095023/ios-country-code/49946377)