# How to get the country code from simCard programatically in ios objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c

Actually I am trying to get the country code programatically from SimCard which is in my phone . How can we get the country code from Simcard programatically . or is there any pod that could help me get the country code details .

Thanks in advance

Comment: try these links http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9095023/ios-country-code
and this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13584981/identifying-the-country-code-using-mobile-carrier-in-iphone-programatically

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**1.** From **SimCard**

```
#import <CoreTelephony/CTTelephonyNetworkInfo.h>
#import <CoreTelephony/CTCarrier.h>

CTCarrier *carrier = [[CTTelephonyNetworkInfo new] subscriberCellularProvider];
NSString *countryCode = carrier.isoCountryCode;
NSLog(@"countryCode: %@", countryCode);
```

**Note** : This code does not work in following conditions:

```
1.Airplane mode.
2.No SIM card in the device.
3.Device is outside the cellular service range.
```

**2.** From **CurrentLocale**

```
NSLocale *currentLocale = [NSLocale currentLocale];  // get the current locale.
NSString *countryCode = [currentLocale objectForKey:NSLocaleCountryCode];
NSLog(@"countryCode: %@", countryCode);
```

Answer (score 4):

You can import:

```
#import <CoreTelephony/CTCarrier.h>
#import <CoreTelephony/CTTelephonyNetworkInfo.h>
```

And using this code:

```
CTCarrier* tmpCTC = [[CTCarrier alloc] init];
NSString* mcc = [tmpCTC mobileCountryCode];
NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"mcc = %@",mcc]);
```

Hope it can help you.

Comment: If you just create a CTCarrier object it will not have any of the information filled in. You must use: CTCarrier *carrier = [[CTTelephonyNetworkInfo new] subscriberCellularProvider]; as in the other answer.

Please edit or remove this answer.

Answer (score 1):

For those who need this in swift.

```
import CoreTelephony

let networkProviders = CTTelephonyNetworkInfo().serviceSubscriberCellularProviders
let countryCode = networkProviders?.first?.value.isoCountryCode
```

Answer (score 0):

The use of `CTCarrier`, a deprecated API, returns static values for apps that are built with the iOS 16.4 SDK or later. (76283818)
[iOS 16.4 Release notes](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/ios-ipados-release-notes/ios-ipados-16_4-release-notes)

As of above change, Apple has not provided a replacement class to read country from SIM code. Fingers crossed on if Apple may delay this change.

[image: Class Documentation Ref]

Unfortunately, we may have to stick to below code to read a country code, which is in deed not a solution.

```
 if let code = Locale.current.regionCode {
    // country code read from the device instead of SIM
 }
```